# Passing numeric parameters to stored procedure in appropriate and easy way

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, c#-2.0

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 which accepts few parameters of type **BigInt** and **Number(18,2)**.

There is a column ApprovedAmount in the database table of type: Number(18,2).

While calling this stored procedure from C# (VS-2005), I am using code like:

```
SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand(Query, CN)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ApprovedAmount",txtApprovedAmount.Text);
```

The above parameter line gives error: **Cannot convert from String to Numeric..**

I find it painful to write the above line as below because there are so many parameters to pass:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ApprovedAmount", Convert.ToDouble(txtApprovedAmount.Text));
```

Is there any easy way to pass parameters so that they are automatically converted to the appropriate database table type in either Stored Procedure itself or with C# code?

I also want to handle a condition that if the TextBox was left blank, the parameter value should be passed as **null**.

Comment: You can make a extension method on the parameters class

Comment: @peer: You can't in C# 2.0 :)

Comment: Use the overload that **explicitly defines** the datatype for your parameter: `cmd.Parameters.Add("ApprovedAmount", SqlDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtApprovedAmount.Text));` - if you use the `.AddWithVAlue`, then ADO.NET must **guess** from the data you pass in what datatype you want - since you pass in a string, it will use a string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(), use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(/*overload that accepts dbType and value*/));
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it, but I believe that you can have the stored procedure take varchar as a parameter, and convert it to a double in the stored procedure. I know in Oracle some types can be implicitly cast, so if SQL Server does the same, you might be able to ignore casting all together (depending on what your stored procedures do).

Comment: I am also thinking that way. To put more and more code in the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the parameter what type it is somewhere, you could write a generic method, but you'll need to specify the type for each call, it's not a huge improvement on what you have

```
private static void AddParameter<T>(SqlCommand cmd, string paramName, string value) where T : IConvertible
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));
}
```

...

```
AddParameter<double>(cmd, "ApprovedAmount", txtApprovedAmount.Text);
```

---

Alternatively, you could subclass TextBox so it has a type, or create new user controls with a `Type` property e.g. Subclassed

```
public class TypedText<T>
    : TextBox 
    where T : IConvertible
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return Convert.ChangeType(Text, typeof(T)); }
    }
}
```

Use these instead of standard TextBoxes, then your add parameter code becomes

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ApprovedAmount", txtApprovedAmount.Value);
```

---

Actually, you could knock yourself out and have an ISPParameter interface that your typed controls implement, this then covers you for booleans from check boxes, dates from datepickers etc.

```
public interface ISPParameter
{
    string Name { get; }
    object Value { get; }
}
public class TypedText<T>
    : TextBox, ISPParameter
    where T : IConvertible
{
    private string parameterName;
    public TypedText(string parameterName)
    {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public object TypedValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ChangeType(Text, typeof(T)); }
    }

    string ISPParameter.Name
    {
        get { return parameterName; }
    }

    object ISPParameter.Value
    {
        get { return TypedValue; }
    }
}
```

with an AddParameter method

```
public void AddParam(SqlCommand cmd, ISPParameter param)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Name, param.Value);
}
```

Then adding parameters becomes

```
AddParameter(cmd, txtApprovedAmount);
```

Hope these give you a few ideas to work on.

Comment: The latter one seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a type-safe language is that you must explicitly cast objects of one type to another as & when required.

With regard to your last point I would read up on c#'s conditional operator (?:) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Which lets you do things like;

```
(txtApprovedAmount.Text == String.Empty) ? null : txtApprovedAmount.Text;
```

Comment: you should use System.DBNull.Value instead of null to stay consistent